# Ionic ENOENT: no such file or director

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using Ionic.

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.1.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.10.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> core.es5.js:1084 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
> ```
>
> '/Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo/src/pages/model/ratingModel.js'
>       Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/Users/richardmarais/Development/ionic/theWhoZoo/src/pages/model/ratingModel.js'

When I try access the following page:

**review/review.ts**

```
...
import { RatingModel } from '../model/ratingModel';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'review.html'
})
export class ReviewPage {
...
```

**model/ratingModel.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { PersonModel } from './personModel';
import { JobModel } from './jobModel';

@Injectable()
export class RatingModel {
        public id: number = null;
        public job: JobModel = null;
        public review: string = null;
        public rating: number = null;
        public reviewDate: number = null;
        public time: string = null;
        public person: PersonModel = null;
        public anonymous: number = null;
}
```

This was working until I changed my pages to use lazy loading.

**review/review.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ReviewPage } from './review';
import { ControlMessagesModule } from '../validation/controlMessages.module';
import { RatingComponentUpdateableModule } from '../utils/rating/ratingComponentUpdateable.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ReviewPage],
  imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(ReviewPage), ControlMessagesModule, RatingComponentUpdateableModule],
  exports: [ReviewPage]
})
export class ReviewPageModule { }
```

**UPDATE**

I find the error occurs because of the following:

```
this.ratingModel = navParams.get('ratingModel');
if (!this.ratingModel) {
  this.ratingModel = new RatingModel();
```

when I remove the `new RatingModel()` line, I don't get any errors.

How are you supposed to create a new `RatingModel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you are making the model class an [*injectable*](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#injectable).

```
@Injectable()
export class RatingModel {
```

You dont have to make a model class as injectable.

*If* you do need to do so, you will have to set it as a provider.
Or try to get an object from the [explicit injector](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#explicit-injector).

```
 constructor(private injector: Injector) { }
 //..
 this.ratingModel = this.injector.get(RatingModel)
```